# How to query posts only with "<img" in its content? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I was working on my personal blog theme, and I want to list all my "image post" (have image(s) in it) to a page, so I built a page template, but don't know how to make WordPress query only those posts with image(s).

I know how to query posts with featured image but my blog is too old and lots of posts don't have a featured image. So if I can search and query post with "

Is there a way to make a custom query to get all posts with

Comment: Take a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I would make a reusable solution: give each post a category (e.g. 'Image only', 'Text', etc.), and query for that category - after I set up all the posts correctly (of course, with thousands of posts this is not really feasible, but up to a couple of hundreds I would do it :) ). If the category is already in use, then some custom taxonomy (or a custom field) would do the trick.

Comment: There's about 1000more posts with or without images in them, it's hard to cat them one by one, besides if I've done that I have to follow the rule when I post new blog posts , it is also not so good, so I still want to find query solution for automatic image list. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I find the solution now, a simple search for "img" tag will perfectly do the job, the query goes like this

```
<?php
// set up or arguments for our custom query
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query_args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
's' => '<img',
'posts_per_page' => 9,
'paged' => $paged
);
// create a new instance of WP_Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); // run the loop 
?>
```